# localStorage doesnt remove parent element

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am trying to remove parent element which is appended but when I try to remove it doesn't work.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
// append
$("#button").click(function(){
    var userList = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
    $('#list').append('<p>' + '&#10148;' + userList + '<input type="submit" value="x" id="delete"/></p>');

    var list=$("#list").html();
    localStorage.setItem('list', list);
    return false;

});

// display `list` on page load
if(localStorage.getItem('list')) {
    $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
}

// when `delete` button is clicked, remove parent of that delete button
$('body').on('click', '#delete', function() {
    var parent= $(this).parent();
    localStorage.setItem('parent', parent);
    window.localStorage.removeItem('parent');
    return false;
});
```

[Jsfıddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tn9dxh83/)

Comment: Requirement is not clear. Can you add an example?

Comment: working for me though

Comment: Deside what you want?

Comment: added fiddle @nikhil

Comment: of course this works, see in my example https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/zxw27msu/

Comment: can you check my fiddle ? @RBoschini

Comment: Why are you even using localStorage for this purpose?

Comment: i am trying to do chrome exension, thats why i am using @AlexBay

Comment: can you check my  fiddle ? @apsillers

Comment: The code is Ok, but I think that it don't do what you are expecting.... the code save the string `[Object object]`  in the localStorage with the `parent` key, but you are not saving the node element. Then you are removing it from the localStorage... so it works, but if you are trying to delete the parent element of the element which has received the click event... you need to change your code.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? I don't understand what you expect to happen that's not happening. You're using the `list` item okay, but in the `delete` listener you set and delete a key called `parent` (note: *not* `list`, which you do use elsewhere) which does nothing at all and is never read. What do you actually want to do here?

Comment: You are appending items with same id.. it must be unique, use class instead

Comment: I am expecting this:When i click the " x " button , localStorage should remove the element i pressed near to "x" button.But does not work. @gabrielperales

Comment: I am expecting this:When i click the " x " button , localStorage should remove the element i pressed near to "x" button.But does not work. @apsillers

Comment: @BurakErman So you actually want `parent.remove();` instead of making and immediately deleting a `localStorage` key called `parent` that does nothing, right?

Comment: Yea.If i use "parent.remove();" it removes okay but, i am trying to make a chrome extension.So when i close and click extension , removed element is still there.So i have to remove it with localStorage @apsillers

Comment: @BurakErman Consider this: when you *add* an element, why are your changes still there when you reopen the extension? Could you apply the same approach to removed items?

Comment: When i reopen my added element are still there.Cos i used localStorage to make them stay.But now i wanna remove them using localStorage again dude..This made heacache.Did you check my fiddle? @apsillers

Comment: @BurakErman Exactly. You add an element, and then store the HTML string to `localStorage`. Why not store the HTML string to `localStorage` every time you make *any* change (add *or* remove)? (I'm trying to help you understand your own approach to saving data.)

Comment: Man ı just wanna remove it, thats all i want now ...... @apsillers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100378/discussion-between-apsillers-and-burak-erman).

Comment: @Burak Erman see this fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/tn9dxh83/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tn9dxh83/17/) to your Fiddle.

It inserts every new item to localStorage separately with a specific key.

```
localStorage.setItem('list_' + itemcount, newitem);
```

This way you can later delete directly the required content.

I changed `id` to `class`, becouse `id`s are unique, and added a unique id to every item.

Answer (score 0):

First, `id` values should be unique. Change your `id="delete"` to `class="delete"` and `#delete` to `.delete`.

Your delete button listener doesn't do anything at all. Right now, it creates a brand-new item in `localStorage` called `parent` and then immediate deletes it.

You need to do two things:

1. Remove the parent element from the DOM. You can do this using the jQuery `remove` method: `parent.remove();`
2. Update your `list` item in `localStorage` to contain the HTML of the new list, just as you do when adding items:

   ```
   var list = $("#list").html();
   localStorage.setItem('list', list);
   ```

So, putting all these points together, you get:

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  var parent= $(this).parent();
  var list=$("#list").html();
  localStorage.setItem('list', list);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @BurakErman I've included the code literal code to do this at the end of the answer. Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @BurakErman I've added the complete function, which is just the two previous points put together in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every value in localStorage is coerced to a string, so it can store the HTML as text but not as an actual DOMElement object - if you try to do that you'll end up with a value something like `"[object HTMLBodyElement]"`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

> The keys can be strings or integers, but the values are always strings

From a higher level, you'll need to justify using `localStorage` - if you want a persistent reference to your variables in the same page lifetime you should just scope a variable outside the event handlers and store the information there. If you want a persistent reference across page views, this can never work - the element will be destroyed when the page is refreshed, and it would never exist in the context of other tabs open to the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make this, create a array object and control this object, encapsulating methods to easy control then.
see example in [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/tn9dxh83/19/).

```
    var listArr = [];

  if(localStorage.getItem('list')!=null){
    eval('listArr =' + localStorage.getItem('list'));
    tableRender();
  }

  $("#button").click(function(){
      var userList = $('#textarea').val();
      listArr.push(userList);
      localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(listArr));
      $('#textarea').val('');
      tableRender();
  });

  function tableRender(){
    $('#list').empty();
    $.each(listArr, function(idx, obj){
      $('#list').append('<p>' + '&#10148;' + obj + '<input type="submit" value="x" data-idx="'+ idx +'" class="delete"/></p>');
    });

     $('.delete').bind('click', function() {
        var idxRemove= $(this).attr('data-idx');
        listArr.splice(idxRemove, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(listArr));
        tableRender();
      });

  }
```